# View old Inbox messages in (OS X) Mail.app via Exchange IMAP?

Tags: email, mac-osx, exchange-2003, imap

We're thinking of migrating our Mac users away from Entourage 2008 and instead using Mail.app (built into OS X Snow Leopard).

We're running SBS 2003 so it's Exchange 2003 for now.

When I setup an "Exchange IMAP" Mail account for a user, their Inbox shows up as empty. However, all of their other folders appear to be populated with their existing email correctly. New email shows up correctly in their Inbox.

What do you have to do to see all of the old messages already in the Inbox?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting `Mailbox > Rebuild` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the IMAP path prefix to use INBOX from `Preferences > Accounts > Advanced` tab.